# Записать текст с консоли в файл

Tags: java

Как сделать что бы данная строка не прерывала вывод в консоль, но при этом продолжала записывать в файл.

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("step.txt")), false));
```

В данный момент все что после данной строки не выводится в консоль

```
        System.out.println("test1");
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("step.txt")), false));
        System.out.println("test2");
```

test1 - будет выведенно в консоль, test2 - нет, но будет записан в файл

Или какая есть альтернатива вывода в файл все что пишется в консоли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться классом [`TeeOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) из библиотеки [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("step.txt");
TeeOutputStream out = new TeeOutputStream(System.out, fos);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out, false);
System.setOut(ps);

System.out.println("test1");
System.out.println("test2");
```

А можно просто вручную выводить в два места:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("step.txt");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos, false);

private void out(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
    ps.println(text);
}
...
out("test1");
out("test2");
```